# LINQ, ASP.net mvc and joins

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am making an application usign MVC and LINQ.

I have a controller called home which does this:

```
    Dim notes = From x In dal.tbl_notes _
                Join y In dal.tbl_note_users On y.user_id Equals x.note_id _
                Select x.note, x.datestamp, y.is_owner, y.note_user_id
    ViewData("notes") = notes
    Return View()
```

And a page called home which has this code for displaying the output:

```
<%  For Each note In ViewData("notes")%>
    <%=Html.Encode(note.ToString)%>
<% next %>
```

However, the output looks like this:

{ note = vbnv, datestamp = , is_owner = True, note_user_id = 1 }

How can i output individual columns (like note or datestamp)? Is there a better way of doing this?

I have tried using viewdata.model but the data is from two different tables, so i can't say what type it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a ViewModel class that contains the note text, date, boolean isOwner, and the user id.

```
Public Class NoteViewModel
     public Note as String
     public DateStamp as DateTime
     public IsOwner as Boolean
     public NoteUserID as Integer
End Class
```

Select this using your the values from the join.

```
Dim notes = From x In dal.tbl_notes _
            Join y In dal.tbl_note_users On y.user_id Equals x.note_id _
            Select new NoteViewModel With { .Note = x.note, _
                                            .DateStamp = x.datestamp, _
                                            .Is Owner = y.is_owner, _
                                            .NoteUserId = y.note_user_id _
                                          }
Return View(notes)
```

Then have your view be strongly typed with the NoteViewModel. This will let you reference Model.Note, etc.

```
<%  For Each note In Model %>
    <%= Html.Encode(note.Note) %>
    <%= note.DateStamp.ToString("M/d/yyyy") %>
    <%= IIF( note.IsOwner, "yes" , "no") %>
    <input type='hidden' value='<%= note.NoteUserId %>' />
<% next %>
```

Comment: Definitely the better way to go. Easier to add other model data to the page when the complexity increases.

Comment: Works almost perfectly, thanks!
The only problem is the
<%--<%= note.IsOwner ? "yes" : "no" %>--%>
part. I get a compildation error when i try to use it.

Comment: Little bit of C# creeping in.  Corrected.

Comment: Thanks! Thought it looked a bit suspiscious ;)